# What is the purpose of the 'figure' tag in html?

Tags: html

I'm using the `<figure>` tag like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<figure>
 <img src="img.jpg" alt="image" width="204" height="220">
</figure>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I remove the `<figure>` tag it doesn't appear to make any difference. Can someone explain to me what the use of the figure tag is?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figura

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of the `<figure>` tag is that it is part of the main flow and if removed, it would not affect the flow of the document (source http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp)

That's why it is mainly used for images, videos, animations etc...

Basically, you can look at it as wrapping tag that doesn't affect the position of its children

Comment: Then why use it?

Comment: In order to be a wrapper is one of the main reasons

Answer (score 14):

Good question.

It all goes down to a few things - **semantic meaning, SEO, accessibility (and maybe more…)**

**What is it?**

The  element is a **semantic tag** that just came out in HTML5. This tells the browser that  is a container that holds elements that have a relation to each other. The  plays a role to this and it will be explained below.

Also, note that it does not have to contain just  element, it can contain other elements such as tables, video clip, audio clips, etc

**Why should we use it?**

Before HTML5, there was no element for captions for images, diagram, video and so on.
It will have a semantic meaning now with  element. The  will help the search engine to find these images.

And with **semantics**, your **SEO** improves and the bots will find your image faster on search engine with it and show it in results.

**Accessibility**

With `figure` and `figcaption` tags, the user (**visually-impaired user**) will be able to understand the structure (with the help of the screen reader).
The screen reader bot will inform the user that this is a caption content, so if it is placed right after or before the related images, the user will be able to understand it.

Answer inspired by: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/why-use-the-figure-element/315116/3

Answer (score 11):

The `<figure>` element is intended to be used in conjunction with the  element to mark up diagrams, illustrations, photos, and code examples (among other things). The spec says this about `<figure>`:

[W3C](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/figure.html)

> The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting the document’s meaning.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

> The HTML `<figure>` element represents self-contained content, frequently with a caption `<figcaption>`, and is typically referenced as a single unit. While it is related to the main flow, its position is independent of the main flow. Usually this is an image, an illustration, a diagram, a code snippet, or a schema that is referenced in the main text, but that can be moved to another page or to an appendix without affecting the main flow.

Comment: Then why use it?

Comment: It's good for accessibility as well to understand layout flow for accessible devices.

Comment: Perhaps add an example to your answer, illustrating the advantages by using it? Those two documentation-descriptions are good for an abstract understanding. But it doesn't really get me closer to knowing if (or when) i should be using `<figure>`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason to use a  tag is because it is HTML5 semantic.  It does not have class traits assigned to it. As the other answers have noted, you can remove it or replace with a div and it really wont change anything.
However if you are writing good 'semantic' code, which defines meaning in its tags then this is one of the standard tags you would include.
It is similar to   or  and other semantic tags which define your code in readable way to the browser and to the developer.